# JS/jQuery - setInterval applies multiple times and too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

Live example: http://www.elplastgdynia.pl/ box left to the man image

As you can see it keeps on blinking like it got stuck on one of the animations. Any ideas what could possibly be going wrong?

JS:

```
function mainHeaderChange() {
    if ($mainheadercounter == 0) {
        $("#module-intro-text .container").animate({opacity: "0"}, 1500);
        setTimeout(
          function() 
          {
            $("#module-intro-text .element h1:nth-child(1)").text("Najwyższa jakość");
            $("#module-intro-text .element h1:nth-child(2)").text("oferowanych usług");
            $("#module-intro-text .element p:nth-of-type(1)").text("Potwierdzona certyfikatem jakości");
            $("#module-intro-text .element p:nth-of-type(2)").text("ISO 9001:2008");
            $("#module-intro-text button").attr("name", "linkto-quality");
          }, 1500);
        $("#module-intro-text .container").fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
        $mainheadercounter++;
    } else if ($mainheadercounter == 1) {
        $("#module-intro-text .container").animate({opacity: "0"}, 1500);
        setTimeout(
          function() 
          {
            $("#module-intro-text .element h1:nth-child(1)").text("szeroka gama");
            $("#module-intro-text .element h1:nth-child(2)").text("przetwarzanych materiałów");
            $("#module-intro-text .element p:nth-of-type(1)").text("Dobierzemy najlepsze tworzywo");
            $("#module-intro-text .element p:nth-of-type(2)").text("do Twojego projektu");
            $("#module-intro-text button").attr("name", "linkto-services");
          }, 1500);
        $("#module-intro-text .container").fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
        $mainheadercounter++;
    } else if ($mainheadercounter == 2) {
        $("#module-intro-text .container").animate({opacity: "0"}, 1500);
        setTimeout(
          function() 
          {
            $("#module-intro-text .element h1:nth-child(1)").text("OD PROJEKTU,");
            $("#module-intro-text .element h1:nth-child(2)").text("do produktu");
            $("#module-intro-text .element p:nth-of-type(1)").text("Przetwórstwo tworzyw sztucznych");
            $("#module-intro-text .element p:nth-of-type(2)").text("w technologii wtrysku");
            $("#module-intro-text button").attr("name", "linkto-offer#processtoproduct");
          }, 1500);
        $("#module-intro-text .container").fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
        $mainheadercounter = 0;
    };
};

$mainheadercounter = 0;
setTimeout(function() {setInterval(mainHeaderChange(), 8000);}, 3000);
```

On request i will create a snippet if the live preview won't be enough to investigate this issue

Comment: try replacing `setTimeout(function() {setInterval(mainHeaderChange(), 8000);}, 3000);`
with `setTimeout(function() {setInterval(mainHeaderChange, 8000);}, 3000);`

Comment: @JFit updated live, still blinks tho

Comment: your timeline seems super messy - I'd recommend that you try to recreate your problem in JSFiddle - way more likely then that someone will help. Trying to recreate this locally would be a real pain. The problem is more than likely with your bunch of timeouts outside and inside of the mainHeaderChange function. Its just too much.

Comment: Also, make sure after you made that previous change that you cleared your cache, cos that probably woulda fixed it. (CTRL+F5)